# 'NoneType' object is not callable in Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new-ish to python and started experimenting with  Beautiful Soup 4. I tried writing code that would get all the links on one page then with those links repeat the prosses until I have an entire website parsed.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request as url

links_unclean = []
links_clean = []
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url.urlopen('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/').read(), 'html.parser')

for url in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(url.get('href'))
    links_unclean.append(url.get('href'))

for link in links_unclean:
    if (link[:8] == 'https://'):
        links_clean.append(link)

print(links_clean)

while True:
    for link in links_clean:
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url.urlopen(link).read(), 'html.parser')

        for url in soup.find_all('a'):
            print(url.get('href'))
            links_unclean.append(url.get('href'))

        for link in links_unclean:
            if (link[:8] == 'https://'):
                links_clean.append(link)

        links_clean = list(dict.fromkeys(links_clean))



input()
```

But I'm now getting this error:

> 'NoneType' object is not callable
>        line 20, in 
>        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url.urlopen(link).read(), 
>        'html.parser')

Can you pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when importing modules `as` something. In this case, `url` on line 2 gets overridden in your `for` loop when you iterate.

Here is a shorter solution that will also give back only URLs containing **https** as part of the **href** attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


content = urlopen('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
base = soup.find('body')

for link in BeautifulSoup(str(base), "html.parser").findAll("a"):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        if 'https' in link['href']:
            print(link['href'])
```

However, this paints an incomplete picture as not all links are captured because of errors on the page with HTML tags. May I recommend also the following alternative, which is very simple and works flawlessly in your scenario (**note**: you will need the package [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/)):

```
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')

for link in r.html.absolute_links:
    print(link)
```

This will output all URLs, including both those that reference other URLs on the same domain and those that are external websites.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using an attribute = value css selector and using the `^` operator to specify that the `href` attributes begin with `https`. You will then only have valid protocols. Also, use set comprehensions to ensure no duplicates and `Session` to re-use connection.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
final = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    httpsLinks = {item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href^=https]')}
    for link in httpsLinks:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        newHttpsLinks = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href^=https]')]
        final.append(newHttpsLinks)
tidyList =  list({item for sublist in final for item in sublist})  
df = pd.DataFrame(tidyList)
print(df)
```